# ImageList in a ListView

Tags: c#, listview, imagelist

I have an image list in a list view where previously the only images displayed were pdf's. This meant that that i could handle the double click event effectively to open pdf's. Now i have a different requirement to display some place holder thumbnails for other files in a folder. Is there a way in the listView_DoubleClick event to determine what picture was clicked in the image list, that way i can determine how to handle the event?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine what item was clicked, when you then have a `ListViewItem` instance you can check for the `ListViewItem.ImageIndex` property.

Edit:
`ListView.SelectedItem` and/or `ListView.SelectedItems` are your friends here.

Comment: how do you mean determine what was clicked? you mean get the sender object of my listview click event and cast it to a listview. Derive from that a ListViewItem object to determine which was clicked?