# Alternative to ImageList Tag

Tags: c#

I asked this question earlier [Get image from list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409097/get-image-from-list-view)

To which i got a reply of "Use the tag field". However after spending all morning trying to do this and the Tag field always being null i got curious and stumbled across this

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/115832/imagelist-does-not-preserve-the-tag-property-of-images-added

`When creating an ImageList and adding an image that has the "Tag" property set to a non-null value, the ImageList does not retain the Tag value for the image. When retrieving the image at a later time from the ImageList, the Tag property of the image is null.`

Now i am pretty stuck, what alternatives are there to using Tag?

Thank you

foreach file in the pdf collection

add it to the image list

determine other files to add

add to the image list

set ListviewImages to imagelist pictures`

Now i want to use the item clicked (a ListViewItem) and determine how to open it (a pdf does a certain task, a custom icon does something else)

Sorry i cant be more precise but i am worried about posting work data/code

Comment: Well, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @David Heffernan Hi-  I have a set of pdf files returned from a database, could be any number, and some other files too. The pdfs thumbnails are always displayed first. I am adding a couple of custom images to represent the other files in the listview. I need to try and determine whether it was a pdf thumbnail clicked or one of my custom icons

Comment: Maybe you code show more code?

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it, what is the difference to your older question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370195/imagelist-in-a-listview

Comment: because i get a listview item that has no data about the picture i clicked associated to it? from what i can see anyway. The only thing i can get is a numerical index specifying what point in the list the clicked item was. This doesnt really help

Comment: You also get the `Index` of the associated image in your `ImageList`.

Comment: yes i see your point, i get an index of the selected item, get the associated picture out of the image list and there we go. The issue now is i have an image object with no idea what image it is, i cant add anything to the tag of the image as it always resolved to null. I need to no because i have 3 custome images that have bespoke functionality when clicked.

Comment: Ok, now i get it. If your Tag-approach is failing then you could try to put the images into a Dictionary<Image, object>. After you get the Image object in the Click event you will be able to get extra information about the Image through the dictionary. You then kinda emulate the Tag of the Image object itself. Maybe you also want to consider using the Tag property of the ListViewItem for this purpose.

Comment: ok i will give this approach a try - thanks very much.